# Subversion web based browser

Tags: svn

What web based interface for browsing **Subversion** repositories do you like the most? We have tried **Viewvc**, but the installation seemed too complex for us.

This is no poll. I'd really love to allow people at the office to be able to access the data at the repositories with their web browsers and see who modified each file and when.

**Subversion** provides web browsing, but is very poor, and [Viewvc](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/63/ViewCVS.png) looks nice but is too hard to install.

I am not talking about **Subversion** clients, but just a web showing the commit history, like at [bitbucket](http://media.bitbucket.org/img/promo/ss1.png). Also, a direct link for a ZIP file for each revision would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I love Fisheye from Atlassian (née Cenqua). It might have too many functions for you taste (searching, auditing and code review support are all part of the package these days), but it has the best interface for browsing SVN (or any VC-system, actually) I have yet encountered.
On the downside, it's commercial (if you're commercial, that is. They provide free instances for OSS-projects) and hardly inexpensive.

You can have a look at their demo-instance at http://fisheye3.cenqua.com,

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at [web-based repository client in VisualSVN Server 3.2 and newer](http://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#).

- It works out of the box and does not require any manual configuration steps,
- Features revision history browser,
- Rendering of *markdown documents*,
- Inline diff for changed files,
- Syntax highlighting.

Answer (score -3):

If you are looking for simplicity, you can browse the repository by just pointing your browser to the repository URL.